# Como Reversar de .NET Core a .NET 4.6 - Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Se necesita volver un proyecto de Web API de Core 2.2 a framework .Net 4.6 y se desarrolla en **codefirst**; en la clase del `dbContext`  se tiene un `OnModelCreating` unos datos iniciales pero sale un error en la linea "hasData":

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Generador>().**HasData**(
        new Generador { Nombre = "xm324", Capacidad = 1000000 },
        new Generador { Nombre = "Bee344", Capacidad = 3000000 },
        new Generador { Nombre = "DCM445", Capacidad = 5000000 }
        );
}
```

en que difieren el .NET Core 2.2 al 4.6?

Comment: Que versión de Entity Framework usas?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta EF 6.0

Comment: En el directorio **Migrations** de tu aplicación, tienes una clase llamada **Configuration.cs**?. Si es así indica el código en la pregunta.

Comment: Sólo por curiosidad, ¿por qué? Esta es la primera vez que veo un downgrade de .net Core a .net Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para insertar datos en tu BD con EF 6 y .NET 4.6, debes de seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. En el archivo de configuración `Configuration.cs` dentro del directorio **Migrations**, debes sobrescribir el método **`Seed()`** de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   internal sealed class Configuration : 
   DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
   {
     public Configuration()
     {
         AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
     }

     protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
     {
       context.Generador.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
           new Generador { Nombre = "xm324", Capacidad = 1000000 },
           new Generador { Nombre = "Bee344", Capacidad = 3000000 },
           new Generador { Nombre = "DCM445", Capacidad = 5000000 }
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. A continuación crea una **migración** para **actualizar** los nuevos datos en la BD.

> PM> Add-Migration MigracionActualizar

3. Por último **actualiza** la BD.

> PM> Update-Database

---

**UPDATE**: Hay que tener en cuenta que el método extensor **`AddOrUpdate()`**, lo que hará es **insertar**(Insert) o **actualizar**(Update) los registros en la BD, cada vez que se realice un **Update-Database** de EF6. Por lo tanto, cada vez que se realice una **migración**, comprobará si existen los registros, y si no los creará. En el caso de ya existir los registros en la BD, solo los modificará si son diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

La opción [HasData](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) al parecer solo está disponible en .Net Core comenzando desde la versión 2.1, para plantar datos (Seed Data) en en las versiones no core de entity framework se usa el método [seed](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx) o bien puedes especificarlas en tus migraciones, crear una migración especifica para popular tus tablas:

```
 protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder mb)
 {
  mb.Sql("INSERT INTO Generador (Nombre, Capacidad) VALUES ('xm324',1000000 )");
  //Mas instrucciones
  }
```

Comment: pero me parece que indicando un objeto así como lo sugiere RafaelAcosta es mas indicada que realizar inserts e invocando comando sql server

Comment: claro, puedes ir por la implementación que mas se adapte a tu necesidad o la estructura que quieres que tu código tenga, de hecho en mi respuesta puedes ver que te dejé un enlace que explica el método seed que es el que Rafael comenta, recuerda que al final lo que entity framework genera son instrucciones sql, asi que el migration builder podría darte mas control sobre el sql a ejecutar, pero al final dependerá de tu necesidad y creo que hasta cierto punto tu comodidad ;)